# How do I get the most recently dated file in a folder in VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm working with some legacy VB6 code and I'm horrible with it. The code below "thinks" its getting the most recent file by using the name of the file. But this method no longer works because it uses digits 0 - 9 to determine this. And it sees 6 as being newer than 2, where that number is the year. For example. the files that need sorting are formatted like this.

```
FORMZZ6.eln is a 2006 file
FORMZZ2.eln is a 2012 file
```

The code below sorts alphabetically. Is it possible to choose the file nased on its last modified date?

```
Private Function ResolveFormVersion(sForm As String) As String
Dim sFile  As String
Dim sFile2 As String

sFile = Dir(BaseDirectory & sForm, vbNormal)

Do
    sFile2 = Dir
    If sFile2 > sFile Then sFile = sFile2 
Loop Until sFile2 = "" 

ResolveFormVersion = sFile

End Function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should be able to rewrite the loop to use the FileDateTime function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262740%28VS.60%29.aspx